# How to prevent two Manupulate functions from effecting each other?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I'm stuck with this problem for the past two days. I'm doing the same set of operations (that involve manipulate with dynamic updating) on two different data. When each one is done individually I'm getting the correct output but when both manupulates are in the same notebook, the first manipulating is just duplicating the second one. I read this has something to do with global variables, but being a beginner thats a little hard to comprehend for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All variable accessed and used inside Manipulate should be internal to Manipulate. Do not use global variables. That is all. i.e. do not write something like

```
x=0
Manipulate[ x=y+1;
            x,
            {{y,0,"y="},0,10,1}
          ]
```

Since now `x` is in global context.  But write

```
Manipulate[ 
            Module[{x=0},
              x=y+1;
              x
            ],
            {{y,0,"y="},0,10,1}
          ]
```

Just need to make sure no variables used are global. Use Modules inside Manipulate to factor your code out and pass everything between them using arguments.

Comment: Thank You. I rewrote all my functions to include only local variables. I'm new to mathematica so I found it a bit counter-intuitive that variables are global by default.